# mysql c how to use load in file Technology?

Tags: c++, mysql, c

use mysql_real_query function just 1000 - 1500/second written to the database
how to use load in file improve efficiency

```
BOOL CDataBase_MySQL::DataBase_MySQL_Execute(LPCTSTR lpszSQLQuery)
{
    DataBase_IsErrorOccur = FALSE;
    pthread_mutex_lock(&st_csDatabase);

    if (0 != mysql_real_query(&st_MySQL,lpszSQLQuery,_tcslen(lpszSQLQuery)))
    {
        DataBase_IsErrorOccur = TRUE;
        DataBase_dwErrorCode = ERROR_HELPCOMPONENTS_DATABASE_MYSQL_EXEC_EXECUTE;
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&st_csDatabase);
        return FALSE;
    }
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&st_csDatabase);
    return TRUE;
}
```

Comment: how many rows are you trying to write? `load data infile` can just speed up the write performance, if you are trying to insert many rows. If you are inserting just a few rows and experience this response time, you may have other problems.

Comment: do you need that mutex?